# Getting CSS3 Transitions to change to Dynamic Height

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a group of div box's that will be displayed at different times based on what is clicked. It needed to be animated to slide down. For this, I change the height of the each div at a certain time, then the CSS3 Transition takes over and eases it down.

Now at the moment, if I provide the height for the box to change to, it works fine, but I can't always provide that as the content is dynamic and may be however tall. But when I define `auto` as the height, then the transition takes it up to 0, then sizes to the content. How can I get it to instead of slide to 0, slide to the height of the div based on the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sadly after much searching, found out that its not possible to do it to auto, but my solution was to find the inner element (the `p` element which was changing) and used the `clientHeight` added with any other constant's and used that as the defined new height. Bit busy, but it works nicely.